# Nginx + FastGgi++

Tags: nginx, cgi, fastcgi, fastcgi++

I'm new in web development, and I need to know how to configure `Nginx` server to use it with `FastCgi++`?

I tried to use this [examples](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/), but I don't nderstand what exact I need to compile for `FastCgi++`, what I need for creating `FastCgi++` process, what I need to pass in `Nginx`, etc.

Please, help me to find some step-by-step instruction/tutorial to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First get fastcgipp lib , find an example say from 
http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/doc/1.2/helloWorld.html
build your program by linking to fastcgipp lib.
Then two  steps are needed
A)Inside nginx config, say...
/etc/nginx/sites-available$ ls
 default
/etc/nginx/sites-available$ vi default

```
server {    location / {
            fastcgi_pass  localhost:9000;           <<< ------ ADD SOMETHING LIKE THIS
            # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
    }
```

B) install spawn-fcgi, and use as below ... where u r application is mySrv
  spawn-fcgi -p 9000 -fn mySrv

Now use u r browser to go to localhost (if anything else is not configured)